# Improving classical processors with simulation or optimization on a quantum computer?

Tags: simulations, quantum-computer, optimization

Two classes of applications for quantum computers are (1) solving [constrained optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization) problems [[example](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025500000529)] and (2) ab initio [simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_simulator) of quantum systems [[review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6253)].  Have there been any concrete proposals for using either technique to improve the design (and hence performance) of *classical* computational hardware devices such as traditional microprocessors?

Using a quantum annealer to optimize datapaths would be an example of (1). 
 Deploying new insights in material science, derived from a quantum simulation, to improve flash memory fabrication would be an example of (2).

Comment: Neither of these count as *hardware* design improvements, but https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.3710 and https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/classical-computing-embraces-quantum-ideas/ give some nice examples of improvements to purely classical *algorithms* that were discovered by thinking about quantum computation.

Comment: Thanks tparker. I'm interested in hardware changes because they potentially speed up *all* computational tasks.  Based on my previous reading about the algorithmic insights you mention, they are interesting but I think they are restricted to rather narrow applications.